# parameter convert from sql server to oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

This parameter in SQL Server query - I copy to the Oracle query I am writing but it does not compile:

> Compilation errors for PROCEDURE OGEN.DBD_NOT_GET_NOTES_DETAIL
>
> Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> := . ) , @ % default character
>   The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue. Line: 6 Text: , NOTETYPE NUMERIC(1) = 1

How can I code this in Oracle?

The complete SQL Server T-SQL query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [OEN].[DB_NOT_GET_NOTES_DETAIL]
(
@FACILITYKEY CHAR(4),
@DATEFROM DATETIME, 
@DATETHRU DATETIME,
@UNITSTR VARCHAR(250),
@NOTETYPE NUMERIC(1) = 1
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT P.FACILITY_KEY, P.PAT_NUMBER, P.PATIENT_ID, 
             OEN.DATEONLY(N.CREATED_ON) CREATED_ON, N.NOTE_HEADER,
             N.CREATED_BY, P.LAST_NAME, P.FIRST_NAME, P.MIDDLE_NAME, P.UNIT_CODE 
       FROM OEN.EN_M_PATIENT_MAST P INNER JOIN OPTC.NOT_M_MAST N
        ON (P.PAT_NUMBER = N.PAT_NUMBER AND N.FACILITY_KEY = @FACILITYKEY)
        WHERE N.NOTE_STATUS = 0 
        AND (OEN.DATEONLY(N.CREATED_ON) BETWEEN OEN.DATEONLY(@DATEFROM) AND OEN.DATEONLY(@DATETHRU))
        AND (@UNITSTR IS NULL OR @UNITSTR = '' OR CHARINDEX(P.UNIT_CODE, @UNITSTR) % 2 = 1)
        AND @NOTETYPE = 1

END
```

The Oracle version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OEN.DBD_NOT_GET_NOTES_DETAIL (
  FACILITYKEY varchar2
, DATEFROM DATE
, DATETHRU DATE
, UNITSTR varchar2
, NOTETYPE NUMERIC(1) = 1


, OCURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) as
BEGIN
  OPEN OCURSOR FOR
    SELECT P.FACILITY_KEY, 
    P.PAT_NUMBER, 
    P.PATIENT_ID,
      OEN.DATEONLY(N.CREATED_ON) CREATED_ON, N.NOTE_HEADER,
             N.CREATED_BY, P.LAST_NAME, P.FIRST_NAME, P.MIDDLE_NAME, P.UNIT_CODE 

      FROM OEN.EN_M_PATIENT_MAST P 
      INNER JOIN OPTC.NOT_M_MAST N ON (P.PAT_NUMBER = N.PAT_NUMBER AND N.FACILITY_KEY = FACILITYKEY)
      WHERE N.NOTE_STATUS = 0 
        AND (OEN.DATEONLY(N.CREATED_ON) BETWEEN OEN.DATEONLY(DATEFROM) AND OEN.DATEONLY(DATETHRU))
        AND CREATED_ON BETWEEN DATEFROM AND DATETHRU
       AND (UNITSTR IS NULL OR P.UNIT_CODE = UNITSTR);
    END;
```

Comment: Please add more detail, like the complete code for the procedure in SQL Server and the complete code that you have for Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters to functions should not have length, scale, or precision.  So the `NOTETYPE` parameter would need to be declared

```
NOTETYPE NUMERIC
```

If you want to assign a default value for a parameter, the syntax is

```
<<parameter declaration>> DEFAULT <<default value>>
```

Putting it together, your parameter declaration should be

```
, NOTETYPE NUMERIC DEFAULT 1
```

As a general stylistic matter, though this probably won't cause any errors

- I would strongly suggest that parameters to procedures be anchored to an appropriate type in the data model.  So, for example, `FACILITYKEY OPTC.NOT_M_MAST.FACILITY_KEY%TYPE`.  That allows the parameter to adjust if in the future you need to do something like increase the length of a column.
- I would strongly suggest adopting a naming convention for parameters that differentiates them from database columns.  Prefixing the parameter names is a popular one (i.e. `p_facility_key optc.not_m_mast.facility_key%type`).  Since you're not using the `@` prefix like you do in SQL Server, it is very easy to inadvertently have a parameter name that matches the name of a column in a table.  Since name resolution gives preference to column names over local variables, that makes it very easy to write code that is inadvertently using a column rather than a local variable.

For example, this function will return every row in the `EMP` table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_emps( empno IN emp.empno%type )
  RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
  l_rc sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  OPEN l_rc 
   FOR SELECT *
         FROM emp e
        WHERE e.empno = empno;
  RETURN l_rc;
END;
```

- Since the goal of this method is to return something to the caller, not to do a computation, it really ought to be declared as a `FUNCTION` rather than a `PROCEDURE` and ought to `RETURN` the `sys_refcursor` rather than having an `OUT` parameter.

Comment: good points Justin. We got into calculations on the SQL server query because when calculating in the program, was taking way too long.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need

```
NOTETYPE NUMBER(1) := 1;
```